# Suspend and resume event handling in MVVM

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, mvvm

In a ComboBox I'm using `ICommand` via `EventTriggers` to execute code when the `SelectionChanged` event occurs:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding DataItems}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedDataItem}">
   <i:Interaction.Triggers>
         <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
               <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding Command}" />
         </i:EventTrigger>
   </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</ComboBox>
```

My Problem is, when I change the property `SelectedDataItem` programmatically the `SelectionChanged` event gets fired. I want to suspend this.

```
private void SomeMethod()
{
    //SUSPEND SelectionChanged event handling here

    SelectedDataItem = new DataItem();

    //RESUME SelectionChanged here
}
```

How can I suspend and resume GUI event handling in MVVM?

Comment: Just put in a flag `private bool ManuallyUpdatingSelectedId = false` then set it to true before you change the item, in the `SelectionChanged` check if that is true before continuing execution.